# Unable to access all the events in a VB web form using Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

When I create a Web Form a large chunk of the events for my objects are missing when I select the control.

Example: `Button` only has the `Click` event and `Label` has no events I can run.

When I created a Windows Form application, the events are all there. What can I do to get my events back?

Comment: try turning off intellisense filtering http://developerpublish.com/how-to-turn-off-intellisense-filtering-in-visual-studio-2017/